# Ajax Rerender working for selectOneMenu, but not input text

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm a bit out of my element here, but I have two panelGroups, one that contains an input field of type text:

```
<input type="text" value="#{myBean.value}" id="myId" >
  <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="divToRerender" oncomplete="jsFunction()"/>
</input>
```

and another that contains a selectOneMenu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}" id="myId" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.options}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="divToRerender" oncomplete="jsFunction()"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

When the selectOneMenu is changed, the div is rerendered perfectly. But when the input field changes, the div isn't rerendered. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a4j:support>` works with JSF components. Replace your `<input type="text">` by `<h:inputText>`.